# Add dependency after deserializing objects

Tags: c#, serialization, dependency-injection, deserialization

I'm developing a software in C# in which a user can filter data objects by applying a successive list of filters. These filters are stored in a list of FilterBase classes which can serialized and later loaded and deserialized. The Filterer class then successively applies these filters to the data set

```
class FilterBase{
   List<Data> Filter(List<Data> data);
}

class ValueFilter : FilterBase{

   public int MaxValue{get;set;}
   public int MinValue {get;set;}
   List<Data> Filter(List<Data> data){
      //Filter by data.Value
   }
}

class Filterer{
   List<Data> data(List<Filter> filters, List<Data> data){
       //loop over all filters and apply them to data
   }
}
```

This works fine, but now I have a new requirement, a Filter that requires user input during the filtering action.

```
class UserInputFilter: FilterBase{

   IUserInputProvider UserInputProvider{get;set;}   

   List<Data> Filter(List<Data> data){
      var input = UserInputProvider.GetUserInput();
      //Filter by data.SomeValue
   }
}
```

Now this class is no longer serializable because it requires the injection of the IUserInputProvider dependency.

My current solution is to use reflection to select the UserInputFilters from the list of deserialized filters, and then inject that dependency, however this seems like an inelegant solution. Is there a pattern to resolve an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just to pass your provider as a parameter to `Filter` method:

```
class UserInputFilter: FilterBase
{
    List<Data> Filter(List<Data> data, IUserInputProvider provider)
    {
        var input = provider.GetUserInput();
        //Filter by data.SomeValue
    }
}
```

Comment: So add the dependency to FilterBase as well?

Comment: if you need this method in `FilterBase` - just place it there.